# error 1178: syntax error in a stored procedure in mariadb columnstore

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, syntax, mariadb, columnstore

I try to produce a stored procedure that allows me to update many tables in my database but when I try to execute it with a columnstore engine, i get an error of procedure syntax not supported. I have looked for it in the web but do not manage to find where is the issue. If you have an idea, I let you the procedure here.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE update_sp_aggregated()
BEGIN
DECLARE finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE tableName varchar(255) DEFAULT "";

DECLARE cursor_update 
CURSOR FOR 
SELECT table_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE table_name like 'sp_aggr%' ;
OPEN cursor_update;
updateAggregated: LOOP
FETCH cursor_update into tableName;
IF finished = 1 THEN 
            LEAVE updateAggregated;
        END IF;

SET @sql = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ', tableName, ' ADD COLUMN col2 varchar(5)');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

SET @sql = CONCAT('UPDATE ', tableName, ' SET col2= LEFT(col1, 1)');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

        END LOOP updateAggregated;
        CLOSE cursor_update;
  END $$

-- declare NOT FOUND handler
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
        FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;
DELIMITER ;

CALL update_sp_aggregated();
```

Comment: so, I have commented alternatively both statements and for the first statement, the add is done but I get an issue because zero rows fetched, selected, or processed. And for the second, it looks that the update is not supported as stored procedure

Answer (score 0):

Finally found, so as tell in my comment, the issue was the update command was not allowed.
to solve it, you need to change the variable infinidb_vtable_mode by setting it to 0.
All is described [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/columnstore-operating-mode/)
and [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/columnstore-create-procedure/)